# How to authenticate firebase with phone number in cordova?

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I develop a Cordova project and I want to authenticate to firebase using phone number.
I use this plugin:
https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

but this not work and force stop when I use

```
window.FirebasePlugin.verifyPhoneNumber("my phone number", timeOutDuration, function(credential) {
    console.log(credential);


    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(signInCredential);
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

and also when i use below method this not work at all:

```
 window.FirebasePlugin.getVerificationID("my phone number",function(id) {
    console.log("verificationID: "+id);
}, function(error) {             
    console.error(error);
});
```

what is the wrong with my code?what can i do?is there another plugin for phone auth in cordova?

Comment: Use https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation found here: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#introduction it seems like Cordova is not currently supported.